# If I create a query string and pass to find() it's not giving error but returning null values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I tried this code as suggested; but it is not taking fieldlist as variable in
    searchstr[k]= {fieldlist:fields[l]};
    I have to create dynamic search string as i have to search on more multiple field combinations.

```
var searchstr={}; 
            // start
          var fieldlist=[ "city", "department"];
            // var fieldlist=["treatment","city","name","facility","department","accreditation"];
            var k=0;
            fieldlist.forEach(function(fieldlist)
            {
                searchstr[k]="";                     
                for(var l= 0;l<fields.length;l++)
                {
                   searchstr[k]= {fieldlist:fields[l]};
                }
             console.log(searchstr[k]);   
            k++;
            });
    console.log(searchstr); 
            // end
          Hospitals.find(
              { $or: [{ searchstr: {city:1}} ]
              } 
               ).sort({'city': 1}).exec(function (err, hospitals) {
                if(err){
                       req.flash("error","Couldn't find hospital for "+strUser);
                       res.redirect("/");
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                ..some code..
                }
```

the searchstr it is showing as 
 { '0': { fieldlist: 'CARDIOLOGY' }, '1': { fieldlist: 'CARDIOLOGY' }
 giving null results; 
 Thanks **Mr. Vito Mario** for reply; can you please suggest something?
 Thanks
 Anurag

Comment: Hi @Anurag could you share you db code or maybe a part of it?

Comment: var hospitalSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type:String,uppercase: true, unique : true, required: true
    },
    city:{
        type:String, uppercase: true, required: true
    },
    reviews:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}],
     costs:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cost'}]
});
Sure this is my Hospital schema ; many other fields are there which i am not able to send full due to character size limitations. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question. Also format your code, nobody wants to dig through a mess of poorly pasted spaghetti code. You may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can see already two issues, first one, you're giving to searchstr a string value I understand you did this on purpose, but you won't get the results you want because mongo can't query through a string but an object, so you should do this instead:

```
searchstr[k]= {fieldlist[k]:fields[l]};
```

So you'll have to declare searchstr as an object. 
Then the other thing is you need to do your query as follows:

```
Hospitals.find( { $or: [{ searchstr: {city:1}, {department: 'foo'}} ]} ).sort({'city': 1}).exec(function (err, hospitals) {
if(err){.some code.} 
else{.some code.}
});
```

This is an example, you can visit mongodb documentation for more information here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/, hope it helps.